# Optimum SSD size for Intel SRT?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, cache

According to Intel, the utilizable cache size on the SSD for SRT is between 18.6 GB and 64 GB.

If I buy a *"64 GB"* SSD I only get 60 GB of usable space, thus underutilizing the SRT technology a bit **and** putting the SSD to maximum stress.

So the question is, **does it make sense to buy a *"128 GB"* SSD** (120 GB usable) for a 50% higher price compared to a *"64 GB"* SSD **to use for SRT?**

This way the full 64 GB will be used for cache and there will be some room left for wear leveling for SSD to perform a little more reliable and fast.

Is that so?

Will the **wear leveling** actually use the whole 120 GB of SSD space in 64 GB SRT mode?